# Why doesn't the form appear if I enable ob_end_clean()?

Tags: php

The code posted is working in the demo environment of the online course I did. On my pc it doesn't work! In order to view the form with the "REQUIRED" statement I have to comment ob_end_clean().

I tried to modify the slashes of the paths, they are correct. I use XAMPP Version 7.2.1 on Windows.

```
function view($view, array $data = []){
    extract($data);
    ob_start();
    require __DIR__.'/../app/views/'.$view.'.tpl.php';
    $data = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $data;
}
```

No error, simply the form is not displayed.

Comment: I'm assuming you `echo view(...)`?

Comment: With the echo view the form appears:     
    public function create(){
        //return view('newPost');
 echo view('newPost');
 //$this->content = view('newPost');
    }

Comment: `view` returns a string, you decide where/when you want to print it.